# How to detect current element's position and cancel an animation in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a web app that uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and I'm updating it to use [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) instead. It is a game in which there is a tile that is animated and falls from the top of the screen until it crashes against the "floor" or against a different object.

I was able to create the animation so the element falls in a linear form from the top to the bottom of the screen like this (mcve):

```js
var wh = window.innerHeight - 40;

d3.select("#tile")
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .style("top", wh + "px")
  .ease("linear");
```

```css
#tile {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background:#336699;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="tile"></div>
```

This works fine if there isn't any object in the way, but if there is, I find two issues:

- With jQuery I use [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) with the `step` method so I can get the current position of the element and that way detect collisions with other elements. **Is there any equivalent to `step()` for `transition()` in d3.js?**
- Once a collision is detected, **how can I cancel the animation so the element stops moving?** (something similar to `stop()` in jQuery).

Doing some research online, I found that I could create an empty transition with a 0 duration and that would answer the second point, but I was wondering if there is a more direct method for that.

Comment: [Cross post](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3015/c%C3%B3mo-detectar-posici%C3%B3n-actual-y-parar-una-animaci%C3%B3n-en-d3-js) in Stack Overflow en Español.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write your own `tween` function, you have complete control over the transition.  At each iteration you can check for collisions and cancel if necessary.

```js
var wh = window.innerHeight - 40;

d3.select("#tile")
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .ease("linear")
  .tween("fall", function() {
    var i = d3.interpolateNumber(0, wh);
    var self = d3.select(this);
    return function(t) {
      var isCollision = (t > 0.5); // some condition to cancel
      if (isCollision) {
        self.transition(); // cancel transition
      } else {
        self.style("top", i(t) + "px");  // continue falling
      }
    };
});
```

```css
#tile {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background:#336699;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="tile"></div>
```

Comment: Quick question: the value of `t` is the percentage completed, right?